# Is it possible for a $\sigma$ algebra to not cover the whole set?

Tags: measure-theory

Could you define a $\sigma$ algebra with sets that only cover part of the space? Like a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ that only has sets from some subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb R\setminus A\in\Sigma$ if $A\in\Sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a sigma algebra on $X$ must contain the set $X$. Of course you can define sigma algebras on some subsets on $X$, but it will not be a sigma-algebra on $X$ then.